# What is the R equivalent package to achieve this scatterplot visualization between variables?

Tags: python, r, data-visualization, correlation, scatter-plot

I am using `R` to perform a `machine learning` analysis and I came across this beautiful data visualization done with `Python`.

I would like to replicate this in `R`. Is there a specific package in `R` that can achieve this? Or may be some online examples of the same visualizations with `R`.

[image: scatterplot visualization]

Comment: Maybe ggplot2 is what you're looking for? http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html#Scatterplot

Comment: You might want to check out the `ggpairs()` function from the GGally package. It produces something similar to what you are seeking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the `pairs` function in R.    Here is an example that is only a modest modification of an example given in the help page `?pairs`.   You need to define a function that plots the histogram on the diagonal  - but the help page provides that code.

```
panel.hist <- function(x, ...) {
    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
    h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
    breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
    y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
    rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, ...)
}

pairs(iris[,1:4], diag.panel=panel.hist, pch=16, col="steelblue")
```

[image: Pairs plot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package but can also just do this using base `R`. You should decide where each single plot (e.g., histogram, scatter plot) goes in the panel. This is an example, also using the R `iris` dataset. I did not format the plots much as that info can be found elsewhere and it is beyond the scope of the question.

```
v1 <- iris$Sepal.Length
v2 <- iris$Sepal.Width
v3 <- iris$Petal.Length

png('panel.png', units="in", width=9, height=9, res=150)
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
hist(v1, main='')
plot(v2, v1)
plot(v3, v1)
 plot(v1, v2)
 hist(v2, main='')
 plot(v3, v2)
  plot(v1, v3)
  plot(v2, v3)
  hist(v3, main='')
dev.off()
```

[image]